# multiple ajax with async doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I call ajax in loop then use the result of those ajax calls, then make another call.As u can see below, in my case I solved it with setTimeout which is an ugly solution.

```
function get_something(some_arr) {
  $.each(some_arr, function(i, obj) {
    //call in loop
    $.ajax({
      url: "example.com",
      complete: function(data) {
        json = data
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console(data);
      },
    });
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'example.com/anothe_endpoint',
      data: {
        data: json
      },
      async: false,
      success: function(data, status) {

      }
    });
  }, 5000);

}
```

How do I execute my second ajax after the ajax in loops in done? I tried to add async to false but without timeout it still failed.

Comment: This is a mess, and will cause you no end of headache, if it works at all. Refer to this documentation on Deferred Objects / Promise structures. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jquery/deferred-objects.html

Comment: @Bosworth99 I did use deferred which .complete() is a promise.

Comment: @Quentin this is not duplicated!

Comment: @CodyJonas — You want to do something after multiple Ajax requests have been made and received responses. That's exactly what the duplicate is about!

Comment: "I did use deferred"... that is not evident in this code. You're just using setTimeout, which could very easily fail.

Comment: @Quentin in the answer, it uses $.ajaxStop, how can I use that? why can't you answer this question? and one of the answer suggested async false, but why it doesn't work in my case?

Comment: @CodyJonas — Why should anyone answer this question? It's the same as another question that already has **eighteen** answers. Incidentally, the accepted and highest rated answer there says not to use `ajaxStop` (and `async: false` is deprecated and shouldn't be used).

Comment: @Quentin assume $.when() helps but I'm using each also, can u helps?